# Java Date toInstant method return a different date?

Tags: java, date

Here is my test code, date of `1111-11-11` to instant method result is `1111-11-17`

```
jshell> new Date(-789,10,11)
$8 ==> Sat Nov 11 00:00:00 JST 1111

jshell> new Date(-789,10,11).toInstant();
$9 ==> 1111-11-17T15:00:00Z
```

Comment: The problem is that handling dates so far in the past has all kinds of issues due to weird calendar switchovers in the past. You might want to consider using dates in this or the previous century.

Comment: Is there something that interests you about the year [1111](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1111)?

Comment: Most of the difference comes from the fact that `Instant` uses the proleptic Gregorian calendar whereas `Date` uses the Julian calendar for dates this far back. Which of them do you want?

Comment: You are probably aware that the 3-arg `Date` constructor has been deprecated since early 1997 and that the `Date` class is long outdated altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone legacy date-time API to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(1111, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
        Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1111-11-11T00:00:00Z
```

## How to do it using the legacy date-time API:

Note that the dates before `1582-10-15` are handled as Julian calendar. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html for more details. Please also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/23460471/10819573 which I've referred to write the following code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        GregorianCalendar proleptic = new GregorianCalendar();
        proleptic.clear();
        proleptic.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
        proleptic.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
        proleptic.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
        proleptic.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1111);
        System.out.println(proleptic.toInstant());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1111-11-11T00:00:00Z
```